# react-hook-form undo the form to previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

i populated a form with react-hook-form's setValue function (i don't know if it is the best way to set up a form in edit mode).

Once the form was touched from a user, i want (on a button click) to restore the form to the state i've previously setted,
(pay attention that i don't want to reset it but, make it again to the value i've previously setted)

```
const { register, handleSubmit, watch, reset, errors, setValue } = useForm();
const { id } = useParams()
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_FBUSER,{
        variables: {_id: id},
        skip: id === undefined
    });
useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            const {_id, id, fbId, name} = data.FBUser[0]
            setValue('_id',_id);
            setValue('id',id);
            setValue('fbId',fbId);
            setValue('name',name);
        }
    }, [data])


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <TextField fullWidth inputRef={register} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} InputProps={{readOnly: true}} name="_id"  label="_Id" variant="outlined" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={8}>
                        <TextField fullWidth inputRef={register} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} InputProps={{readOnly: true}} name="id"  label="Id" variant="outlined" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextField fullWidth  inputRef={register} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}  name="name"  label="Name" variant="outlined" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextField fullWidth error={errors.fbId} inputRef={register({required : true})} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true , required: true}}   name="fbId"  label="Facebook Id" variant="outlined" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextField fullWidth  inputRef={register}  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}  name="note"  label="Note" variant="outlined" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" startIcon={<SaveIcon/>}>Salva</Button>
                        <Button  onClick={reset} variant="contained" color="primary" startIcon={<CancelIcon/>}>Annulla</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass an object with form fields values in reset method.

```
reset({
  type: "contact",
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
})
```

If you set default initial values in useForm hook, invoking *reset()* result in form fields setted to your initial values, but if you pass an object with different data, the fields are setted to values you passed.

So in your case you should save the form state in a particular moment, maybe with *getValues()*, then on button click set the values you wanted.

Docs:
[Reset - React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#reset)

Example:
[Reset Example - Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-reset-v6-forked-tlyf3?file=/src/index.js:1259-1374)

Comment: or simplier, to setup the form in edit mode  should set its initial values (instead of setValue()) and call simply reset(), right?

Comment: exactly, it's much more convenient to have initial values in an object, even if they are empty, so you can use the same object structure for form validators like yup and have a cleaner view of your form structure and values. Personally I define often empty initial values and then on useEffect call I update them. Storing the initial values object in a variable allows me to simply call `form.reset(initialValues);` for restore its initial state.